# Как сделать чтобы в переменой (а) менялась буква?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы в переменой (а) менялась буква?

Может есть какой то более простой способ.

```
for (var a ="B"; a < "E"; a++) {
          Sheet.getRange(a + i).setValue(value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как сделать чтобы в переменой (а) менялась буква?

Для того, чтобы "менялась" буква, нужно перевести её в числовое значение по таблице `ASCII`.

```js
for (var a = "B".charCodeAt(); a < "E".charCodeAt(); a++) {
  console.log(a, String.fromCharCode(a));
}
```

- `charCodeAt()` - возвращает числовое значение символа по *таблице ASCII*
- `String.fromCharCode(<number>)` - возвращает символ из полученного числа по *таблице ASCII*